# How to plot horizontal line in Timeseries in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I use grafana to plot timeseries data. In a timeseries plot i want to add a constant line which comes from a monitoring level. The value of that level is dynamic (from a postgres database) the timeseries come from a ifluxdb Datasource.

The monitoring level have no timestamp. The result should look like this:

[image]

I have searched quite a while how to do this, but not found a good explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to add dynamic thresholds using the **Config from query** option.

1. Add a new query below your standard metric query. This will likely be called `B` (*tip: rename this to something more descriptive)*.

   Here you query the static reference value.
   Eg `SELECT expected_number_of_widgets FROM baseline`
2. Open **Transformation** tab
3. Find **Configuration from Query results**
4. Choose **Config query = `B`**
5. At the dropdown for `expected_number_of_widgets`, choose **Use as: Threshold1.**
6. In the right panel, under **Thresholds**, make sure **Show Tresholds** is enabled and remove the default threshold of 80.

For more details, see https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#config-from-query-results

Comment: Good solution, I tried it, but could not make threshold to be visible, though "Show Thresholds" was set to "As lines".

Answer (score 6):

You can now add thresholds (bottom of the edit screen).

Each threshold can be represented as a solid line and/or region with individual color

[image]

Comment: How can you read the thresholds from a datasource?

Comment: I don't know if thresholds can be dynamically read from a datasource (I understand that's what you want to do?). At time of writing the above answer all you could do what hard code them if I remember correctly.

edit: @HTE seems to have a solution for dynamic threshold

Answer (score 2):

To draw a line like that you have to "fake" a timeseries. (thresholds don't work since they can not be dynamic as far as I know)

First thing to keep in mind is that grafana needs timestamp to plot it, for this reason the global variables ${__to} and ${__from} come in handy.

Then, to draw a line, grafana needs at least two points. ([t0, t1][y0, y1])

So this is the sql (postgre) query that lead to the desired result:

```
SELECT
  ${__from} AS time,
  level_1,
FROM my_table where display_name = '${my_grafana_var:raw}'
union all
SELECT
  ${__to} AS time,
  level_1,
FROM my_table where display_name = '${my_grafana_var:raw}';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it in a dirty way is to create panel with a mixed data source.
Create your variable in grafana - it can be a query, constant or custom. Just remember to keep it a single floating point.
Add your original query and add the prometheus data source to query your variable.

```
${net_ordered_storage}
```

You will have to play a little bit with the number of data points displayed (query options>max data points) and minimum step of data point in prometheus query to make grafana connect dots.

[Green horizontal line from variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahY14.png)