# Grafana: Configure from query: Threshold: All Values - seems not to work

Tags: grafana, transformation, threshold, timeserieschart

I found some really helpful advice in [How to plot horizontal line in Timeseries in Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393244/how-to-plot-horizontal-line-in-timeseries-in-grafana) and now I would like to apply this to my Timeseries Chart with multiple thresholds.

My data source provides thresholds as 2d array:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
100, 200, 300, 400
101, 201, 301, 401
```

the first line is the header ;)

An Example configuration looks like:
[image: Data Source configuration]

and the transformations:
[image: chart and transformations]
As you can see, if I select "Last" in the Transformation, I get one threshold-line each. Here 101 and 201. But if I select "All unique Values", I get no threshold line at all.

I expected to get in total 8 threshold lines (if I select "All unique Values" for each field). How can I archive that? Is there a bug or missunderstanding here?

Comment: Official documentation for this transformation recommends using rows to fields for multiple rows, though I'm not sure it works, or at least works as expected. Those transformation being beta, might have some problems. Consider searching in grafana's issues (and maybe filing your own issue if nothing found)